# "Lame tag CRC check failed" using eyeD3 to change mp3 file tags (Python)

Tags: python, eyed3

I have a lot of mp3 files that are titled in the following format:
"Artist - Song"
Where both the artist and song are in the 'title' field of the file. I would like to change them all to have the artist and song in their respective fields.

To do this, I am using the eyed3 python module. However, when I run my code I get an error message: "Lame tag CRC check failed", and none of the file properties are changed. Here is the code I currently have:

```
import os
import eyed3

for files in os.listdir("C:/Users/justi/Desktop/New Music - Copy"):
    artist_and_song = files.split(".")              # Gets rid of ".mp3" suffix
    split_at_dash = artist_and_song[0].split("-")   # Separates artist and song
    artist = split_at_dash[0]
    song = split_at_dash[1]

    # Loads each and every MP3
    mp3 = eyed3.load("C:/Users/justi/Desktop/New Music" + '/' + files)  
    mp3.initTag()
    mp3.tag.artist = artist
    mp3.tag.title = song
    mp3.tag.save()
```

I have seen this question elsewhere on StackOverflow and none of the suggested solutions did the trick. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the files were generated incorrectly in the first place and this program is exposing it? If you don't make any tag changes do you still get an error? Do you get an error from a file that you obtain from somewhere else?

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm not sure if they were generated incorrectly - I downloaded them from a youtube to mp3 converter. Is there any way I check to see if they were incorrectly generated?

I tried editing the tags in the file properties and then running them through, and nothing changed. 

I'm not sure how I'd be getting an error for another while since I am searching in a folder containing only mp3 files.

Comment: I was able to do this with following script: https://gist.github.com/ZachSaucier/f51e608ac75e8ed6e96cd54a9ec103b0

Comment: @ZachSaucier : ok but your  proposal doesn't fix the Lame tag CRC, the issue is inside the file and it remains. I'm seeking for a solution to fix the CRC ...

Comment: @herve-guerin (@Mari in general) I saw you answered another question on this issue. If you're still looking, I posted an answer on that one that does attempt to address the CRC error itself.